# Spark Streaming: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: <input_filename>._COPYING_

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

I am writing a spark streaming application which reads input from HDFS. I submit spark application to yarn and then run a script which copies data from local fs to HDFS.

But Spark application starts throwing fileNotFoundException. 
I believe this is happening because spark is picking up files before it is being copied fully onto HDFS.

Following is the some part of exception trace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: <filename>._COPYING_
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:56)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsUpdateTimes(FSNamesystem.java:1932)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1873)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1853)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1825)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:559)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.getBlockLocations(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:87)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:363)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1060)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2038)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
```

Any suggestion how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4314

Comment: Solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42041110/hdfs-java-io-filenotfoundexception-file-does-not-exist-name-copying

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your data producer filename the current file being copied different from the completely copied file. Then you need to add filter on file dstream getting the completely copied file only. E.g.

Ongoing copy file prefix _copying*
Completely copies file prefix data*