# Spark Streaming textFileStream COPYING

Tags: scala, hadoop, spark-streaming

I'm trying to monitor a repository in HDFS to read and process data in files copied to it (to copy files from local system to HDFS I use hdfs dfs -put ), sometimes it generates the problem : Spark Streaming: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: .*COPYING* so I read the problems in forums and the question here [Spark Streaming: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: <input_filename>._COPYING_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35643791/spark-streaming-java-io-filenotfoundexception-file-does-not-exist-input-file) 
According to what I read the problem is linked to Spark streaming reading the file before it finishes being copied in HDFS and on Github : 
https://github.com/maji2014/spark/blob/b5af1bdc3e35c53564926dcbc5c06217884598bb/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/FileInputDStream.scala , they say that they corrected the problem but only for `FileInputDStream` as I could see but I'm using `textFileStream`
When I tried to use `FileInputDStream` the IDE throws an error the Symbol is not accessible from this place.
Does anyone know how to filter out the files that are still COPYING because I tried :

```
var lines = ssc.textFileStream(arg(0)).filter(!_.contains("_COPYING_")
```

but that didn't work and it's expected because the filter should be applied on the name of the file process I guess which I can't access 
As you can see I did plenty of research before asking the question but didn't get lucky ,
Any help please ?

Comment: at what point in your code do you get the error? Immediately after the streaming or at the first transformation?

Comment: @Vale this error doesn't appear all the time, I did a shell program that puts the files in HDFS and it runs well with Spark Streaming until at a point I get that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I had a look: [-put is the wrong method](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4314). Look at the final comment: you have to use `-rename` in your shell script to have an atomical transaction on the HDFS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but could you please explain to me how I use rename ? do you mean that instead of using "hdfs dfs -put fileName directoryName " I should use "hdfs dfs -rename fileName directoryName" ?

Comment: `hadoop fs -mv oldName newName` for atomically moving files and renaming them (rename is not in hadoop; I was mistaken, sorry!)

Comment: thank you, but I'm confused because this command doesn't have the destination directory and I don't know the old name since I'm moving files from local files

Comment: No no no, the newName can be the destination directory! `hadoop fs -mv yourFile destinationDirectory/yourFile`
If it's from local, there may be a problem: [look at the documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#moveFromLocal). It is not possible to simply "move", the file is copied and then deleted in local. You should test it. Please remember to mark my answer!

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: streaming doesn't recognize moved files in my case... any suggestions ?