# HDFS : java.io.FileNotFoundException : File does not exist: name._COPYING

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

I'm working with Spark Streaming using Scala. I need to read a .csv file dinamically from HDFS directory with this line:

```
 val lines = ssc.textFileStream("/user/root/")
```

I use the following command line to put the file into HDFS:

```
hdfs dfs -put ./head40k.csv
```

It works fine with a relatively small file.
When I try with a larger one, I get this error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.FileNotFoundException): File does not exist: /user/root/head800k.csv._COPYING
```

I can understand why, but I don't know how to fix it. I've tried this solution too:

```
hdfs dfs -put ./head800k.csv /user
hdfs dfs -mv /usr/head800k.csv /user/root
```

but my program doesn't read the file.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

PROGRAM:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._
import scala.sys.process._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{KafkaProducer, ProducerConfig, ProducerRecord}
import java.util.HashMap
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{LongWritable, NullWritable, Text}
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import StreamingContext._

object Traccia2014{
  def main(args: Array[String]){
if (args.length < 2) {
  System.err.println(s"""
    |Usage: DirectKafkaWordCount <brokers> <test><topicRisultato>
    |  <brokers> is a list of one or more Kafka brokers
    |  <topics> is a list of one or more kafka topics to consume from
    |
    """.stripMargin)
  System.exit(1)
}

val Array(brokers,risultato) = args
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Traccia2014")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(5))

  val lines = ssc.textFileStream("/user/root/")

 //val lines= ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](directory="/user/root/",
     // filter = (path: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path) => //(!path.getName.endsWith("._COPYING")),newFilesOnly = true)

  //********** Definizioni Producer***********

val props = new HashMap[String, Object]()
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers)
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
  "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
  "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")

val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)

val slice=30

lines.foreachRDD( rdd => {

     if(!rdd.isEmpty){
         val min=rdd.map(x => x.split(",")(0)).reduce((a, b) => if (a < b) a else b)
         if(!min.isEmpty){
             val ipDst= rdd.map(x => (((x.split(",")(0).toInt - min.toInt).toLong/slice).round*slice+" "+(x.split(",")(2)),1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
             if(!ipDst.isEmpty){
                val ipSrc=rdd.map(x => (((x.split(",")(0).toInt - min.toInt).toLong/slice).round*slice+" "+(x.split(",")(1)),1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
                 if(!ipSrc.isEmpty){

                    val Rapporto=ipSrc.leftOuterJoin(ipDst).mapValues{case (x,y) => x.asInstanceOf[Int] / y.getOrElse(1) }

                    val RapportoFiltrato=Rapporto.filter{case (key, value) => value > 100 }
                    println("###(ConsumerScala) CalcoloRapporti: ###")
                    Rapporto.collect().foreach(println)
                   val str = Rapporto.collect().mkString("\n")

                      println(s"###(ConsumerScala) Produco Risultato : ${str}")

                      val message = new ProducerRecord[String, String](risultato, null, str)
                      producer.send(message)

  Thread.sleep(1000)


                 }else{
                   println("src vuoto")
            }
                 }else{
                    println("dst vuoto")
             }
             }else{
                println("min vuoto")
            }
                }else
                { 
                 println("rdd vuoto")
              }

              })//foreach


ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()


} }
```

Comment: "but my program doesn't read the file"... `/usr` does not exist in HDFS. Typo... And you should ideally put into your own user folder, not the base `/user` folder

Comment: **doing -put is the wrong way to upload files to HDFS for testing fileStream** https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4314

Comment: at first I was using val lines = ssc.textFileStream("/user/root/")
It works perfectly, but when I try to put into HDFS a larger file, I get the error mentioned. Filestream() is the solution proposed by rogue-one but it doesn't work

Comment: Because he has a typo. `endsWith("._COPYING_")`

Comment: Hi, i have similiar problem that happened with kafka to hdfs, would you mind to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62532940/kafka-connector-to-hdfs-java-io-filenotfoundexception-file-does-not-exist please. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

`/user/root/head800k.csv._COPYING` is a transient file that is created while the copy process is on going. Wait for the copy process to complete and you will have a fail without the `_COPYING` suffix ie `/user/root/head800k.csv`.

to filter these transient in your spark-streaming job you can use the `fileStream` method documented [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext@fileStream[K,V,F%3C:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[K,V]](directory:String,filter:org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path=%3EBoolean,newFilesOnly:Boolean,conf:org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)(implicitevidence$10:scala.reflect.ClassTag[K],implicitevidence$11:scala.reflect.ClassTag[V],implicitevidence$12:scala.reflect.ClassTag[F]):org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[(K,V)])
as shown below for example

```
 ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](
      directory="/user/root/",
      filter = (path: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path) => (!path.getName.endsWith("_COPYING")), // add other filters like files starting with dot etc
      newFilesOnly = true)
```

**EDIT**

since you are moving your file from local filesystem to HDFS, the best solution is to move your file to a temporary staging location in the HDFS and then move them to your target directory. copying or moving within the HDFS filesystem should avoid the transient files

Comment: yes I know it, the problem is that textFileStream() is a listener on HDFS directory (user/root). When a new file is loaded into this directory, it reads the file, but if the file is a transient one he can't read the file anymore and i get the error.

Comment: @MaurizioCacace I have updated the answer for filtering these transient files

Comment: thanks it seems a good solution but I get a new error:
value split is not a member of (org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable, org.apache.hadoop.io.Text), in another part of my program

Comment: @MaurizioCacace can you share the code and your sample file. will debug it

Comment: @MaurizioCacace i have updated the answer to provide a simpler and easier solution.

Comment: updated my question too (y).
Actually, I've already tried to put the file into a temporary directory and then move it into /user/root but it doesn't work because my program can't read the new file I don't know why exactly. No errors are generated, it goes on waiting for a new file

Comment: Hi, i have similiar problem, would you mind to check out mine? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62532940/kafka-connector-to-hdfs-java-io-filenotfoundexception-file-does-not-exist